# Get a web page every 5 hours

Tags: shell

how would a script that loads a URL with wget or possibly another method every 5 hours look like?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To schedule a task to run at regular intervals on a Unix system, one usually uses `cron`.

You should have a look at the `crontab` manual (`man 5 crontab`).

To add a task that runs every fifth hour, edit your `crontab` by issuing the command

```
$ crontab -e
```

This will open your current `crontab` in an editor, or a blank file if you didn't previous have one.

The add the following `cron` schedule to the file:

```
0 */5 * * * /usr/bin/wget -O "$HOME/result" "http://server/page"
```

Correct this for the path to the `wget` executable on your system, and modify the command to suit your needs.

The five first fields on the line is the actual schedule, and the `*/5` in the second field means "every fifth hour".

When you are done, save the `crontab` in the editor and exit.

The command should now run every fifth hour.

Comment: At the risk of being pedantic, speaking literally, this would not run it every 5 hours, but would rather run it 0,5,10,15,20 hours of every day, the last run through would be 4 hours, not 5, since at 0 hours the next day, it starts again. Again, this is being pedantic, because unless the person literally wants to run it every 5 hours, your answer is exactly right. Your answer was certainly better than the question deserved, however.

Comment: Exactly what I needed, thank you Kusalananda. I'm new to Linux and am sorry for writing an incomplete answer. It doesn't have to be exactly every 5 hours, I just felt it is a good enough time to do the task again.